# ExtJS: Overriding OnEsc in message box

Tags: extjs, event-handling

Can't make 'onEsc' handler to work on the message box. When overridden with emptyFn, ESC key press still closes the dialog. Custom onEsc is just never triggered.

```
Ext.Msg.show({
            msg: "message",
            title: "title",
            maxWidth: 420,
            minWidth: 300,
            onEsc: Ext.emptyFn
        });
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1eqo

Comment: thanks. how would I stop it from beforeclose?

Comment: I'll check the answer. tried closable - it just removes red Cross button. any idea why onEsc doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `onEsc` is the property on the instance and can't be applied to a singleton `Ext.Msg`. The solution is to set it on the new instance of `Ext.window.MessageBox` class:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.MessageBox', {            
    onEsc: Ext.emptyFn}).
show(<config>);
```

or

```
new Ext.window.MessageBox({            
    onEsc: Ext.emptyFn}).
show(<config>);
```